# Repair WAMP Server

Tags: php, wamp, wampserver

I cannot put my WAMP server online. I recently add a php extention (php_mssql.dll)
and after checking the extension, my wamp server does not start anymore. I was only able
to remove the extension i added by commenting out the php_mssql.dll in the php.ini file but still it does start and remain color yellow. every time i click "put online" an error message prompt:

Could not execute menu item (internal error)
[Exception] Could not perform service action:
The requested control is not valid for this service

What does this error mean? How do i address this error?

P.S.
I have two servers running MSSQL Server and WAMP Server, prior to adding extension everything works fine and there has been no problem. Also my wamp server is using port 8000.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8637907/wamp-server-does-not-start-after-adding-extension

Comment: You are not supposed to create duplicate Questions for the same issue.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8637779/wamp-server-does-not-start and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8637907/wamp-server-does-not-start-after-adding-extension are possible duplicates of this issue. If you want to add some information in your original question, just edit it and add more information.

Comment: Sorry if i have it duplicated, Im just very desperate at the moment to solve this problem. I already have thousand of data saved on my database and i need the server running again asap.

Comment: @Jayzee: Duplicating a question because you are desperate is *not* accepted on SO.  If your original question is not gaining enough attention, then it's usually an indication that it's a problem with the question.  Replicating questions like this might result in further moderator action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Look in the Apache error logs.  If you find anything, cut/paste the error text above.
2. Look in the Windows error logs.  Similarly, cut/paste any error messages you might find.
3. Failing all else:

   a) Save a backup of your mysql database

   b) Save a backup of your HTML, CSS, PHP, images and custom scripts

   c) Reinstall

Comment: Im already considering reintalling but how do i back up mysql database if i cannot access phpmyadmin? Is it the one in bi/mysql/data?

Comment: this is the error i found on my apche_error log: [Tue Dec 27 00:14:37 2011] [notice] Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server.
[Tue Dec 27 00:14:37 2011] [notice] Child 444: Exit event signaled. Child process is ending.
[Tue Dec 27 00:14:38 2011] [notice] Child 444: Released the start mutex
[Tue Dec 27 00:14:41 2011] [notice] Child 444: All worker threads have exited.
[Tue Dec 27 00:14:41 2011] [notice] Child 444: Child process is exiting
[Tue Dec 27 00:14:41 2011] [notice] Parent: Child process exited successfully.